# Access property of current SKScene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm testing out a few different technologies to integrate into my Sprite Kit-powered game, and I'm stumbling on what I'm sure is a simple task.

The test project I'm using came as part of a framework that integrates [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/) with Sprite Kit. Everything is contained (and defined) in a single ViewController (which creates one of four views depending on which option of a `UISegmentedControl` is currently selected). At the bottom of the screen I have a `UISwitch` which is hooked up to an action:

```
-(IBAction)changeCostume:(UISwitch *)sender {

    if(sender.on) {
        NSLog(@"New costume");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Old costume");
    }
}
```

The scene I'm working on is defined like this:

```
+ (SKScene *) buildAvatarWithSize:(CGSize) size
{
    SpineSkeleton *avatar = [DZSpineSceneBuilder loadSkeletonName:@"test-avatar" scale:1]; //json
    spSkeleton_setSkinByName(avatar.spineContext->skeleton, "test-avatar");
    spSkeleton_setSlotsToSetupPose(avatar.spineContext->skeleton);

    DZSpineSceneDescription *sceneDesc = [DZSpineSceneDescription description];

    ... define animations etc. here...

    NSArray *nodes = [sceneDesc buildScene];

    SKNode *placeHolder = [SKNode node];
    placeHolder.position = CGPointMake(100, size.height);

    placeHolder.name = @"root";

    ... more setup code...

    SKScene *scene = [[SKScene alloc] initWithSize:size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    scene.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [scene addChild:placeHolder];

    return scene;
}
```

The property I want to access is `sceneDesc` - I need to modify its contents on the fly, when the `UISwitch` is pressed. I know that it's possible from within the scene setup code, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do so once the scene's on screen.

Changing values of this property will alter the `SKTexture` used in various nodes.

It probably doesn't help that I'm still new to Objective-C, and the setup of the project is rather different to how I've been working so far (splitting up scenes into their own classes, with properties that can be easily accessed programatically).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSNotificationCenter to send a message to the scene when the switch is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

I actually gave up on trying to access `sceneDesc` programatically, and just changed the textures of the relevant `SKSpriteNode`s:

```
SKSpriteNode *root = (SKSpriteNode *)[placeHolder.children[0] childNodeWithName:@"root"];

SKSpriteNode *arm = (SKSpriteNode *)[root childNodeWithName:@"upper arm"];

SKSpriteNode *upperArm = (SKSpriteNode *)[arm childNodeWithName:@"upper arm"];
SKSpriteNode *lowerArm = (SKSpriteNode *)[[arm childNodeWithName:@"bone3"] childNodeWithName:@"lower arm"];

upperArm.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_sleeve_upper"];
lowerArm.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_sleeve_lower"];
```